# How can I get a count of values for one column as compared to a second column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet with a list of companies that submit data, the type of data they submit, and the date they submit. I need to a do a count of the number of times per day they submit, but only do it based on the company that submits and the program that submits. My first column is the name of the company, second is the type of data they submit, and third is the date. So basically what I need to know how many times the company (a) submits a program (b) per day (c). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please update your question with an example input and expected output. It would really help understand what exactly you're looking for.

Comment: I would love to, but cannot find where to upload. Please assist with where to find this.

Comment: Welcome to Super User, Dan. We are here to help, but this is not a service site where you can place an order for use to do it for you. In this format, we expect to see some effort on your part. Tell us what you have attempted so far and where you have gotten stuck will help a great deal. Reading **[ask]** may help understand how the site works.

Comment: You can upload text to pastebin, or images to imgur.com and then post the links here. You can also use [markdown formatting](http://superuser.com/editing-help#code) to type it in directly into your question.

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't sure if there was a direct upload feature. Unfortunately, such things are not allowed on the network I am on.

Comment: Have you tried using [COUNTIFS](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/COUNTIFS-function-53c4dc8e-0e5b-4e32-93df-9ca5e7da89ed?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Pivot Table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-PivotTable-or-PivotChart-report-d09e4d07-8cd6-4b60-afad-8fb67418800f?CorrelationId=039ade79-81cf-4512-a82d-cac2a4adcade&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#_Toc263767342), it's really easy to do exactly what you want with just a few clicks once you learn how to use that feature.

[image]

- To create a PivotTable or PivotChart report, you must connect to a data source and enter the report's location.
- Select a cell in a range of cells, or put the insertion point inside of a Microsoft Office Excel table.
- Make sure that the range of cells has column headings.
- Select the type of report to generate by doing one of the following:
- To create a PivotTable report, on the Insert tab, in the Tables group, click PivotTable, and then click PivotTable.

[image]

Comment: Please assist with some instructions on how to do this. Thank you.

Comment: I have added an example although I think that was your job, dude. The instructions are completetly from the link I've already give you. So please try it - a kind of learning by doing, i't really easy!

Comment: Thank you. But that doesn't explain to me how to get the data mined to where I want it. I've got the table set up. Can you explain to me how I can narrow down the data to where it'll show how many times a company (a) submitted a certain data type (b) on a certain date (c)? Any help is appreciated. Thank you. I have the columns and fields set up, but it's not giving me the counts per program per company per day.

Comment: Dan, please keep in mind this is not an educational site and is a poor format for teaching. There are a lot of resources on the Internet to teach you how to use pivot tables.